# Solve the inequality $\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}}<\frac{25}{4}$

Tags: inequality

> $$\frac{2}{5}^{\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}}<\frac{25}{4}$$

I can write this as 
$$\frac25 ^{\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}} <\frac25 ^{-2}$$
Therefore $$\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}<-2$$
Solving it , we get $x\in (-2, -\frac 25)$

The correct answer is $x\in (-\infty , -2)\cup (-\frac 25 , \infty)$

I feel it’s got something to do with signs. Maybe in the part where I wrote $\frac 25 ^{-2}$

If I change the inequality there, I arrive at the answer. But I disagree. I haven’t changed the number at all, so the sign should not change. What’s the right answer?

Comment: I think it must be $$\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}>-2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you performed from step $2$ to step $3$ is taking of logarithms.

It is true that if $x<y,$ then $\log x<\log y$ whenever we take the base of our logarithms to be $>1,$ which we usually do. However, in this case, your base $2/5$ is less than unity, so your logarithm function here is monotonically *decreasing,* not increasing. Thus, what we have here is that if $x<y,$ then $$\log x > \log y.$$ This is why you ought to have reversed the inequality when taking logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\frac25<1$, higher exponents will result in smaller numbers.  That is why the inequality needs to be reversed when you switch to the inequality with just the exponents.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{6-5x}{2+5x}<-2$$

After this cross multiply

We get

$$6-5x<-4-10x$$
$$ 10<-5x$$
$$2<-x$$

Now when we multiply or divide by both sides then inequality sign changes

We get

$$2*-1>-x*-1$$
$$-2>x$$

Here was your mistake

Comment: I don’t think we can just cross-multiple variables in inequalities

Comment: Actually we can cross multiply

Comment: I don’t think we can.

Comment: I don't know from where you study mathematics but we can cross multiply

Comment: Not when you have a variable. To be fair, I don’t know where you studied maths either

Comment: See if denominator is positive then you *CAN* cross multiply

Comment: BTW, I have studied mathematics from Stanford.

Comment: Well you DONT KNOW that the denominator is positive. I don’t know if you completed it later on in the answer, cause I really can’t understand whatever you typed up there

Comment: Just multiply both sides with (2+5x)

Comment: Do you know for sure that 2+5x is positive? Cause that is the question asked, and you cannot assume it is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$a^x>a^y\implies \begin{cases}x>y&,\quad a>1\\x<y&,\quad 0<a<1\end{cases}$$